# How to get rid of Big yellow exclamation mark in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I downloaded a modified Emacs from vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/, I'm not sure if it is that to be blame, but every time when input error or scroll to the last in emacs, it shows a yellow big exclamation mark like this. How to get ride of this? Thank you so much. 
[screenshot of this mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1cnH.png)

Comment: 1. That's pretty funny. 2. I suggest not using that modified version of Emacs, if you don't like its modifications?

Comment: It looks like the visual bell, and if so, there are several threads that explain how to turn this off:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlarmBell  The build by Vincent Goulet should, in theory, actually save novice Emacs users a ton of time configuring the proper display of images within Emacs (e.g., the Windows version, that is) and using third-party libraries that come pre-installed.

Comment: Thanks you guys, this link also helped me a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the `visible-bell` variable to `nil` or the `ring-bell-function` variable to `'ignore`. E.g.,

```
;; you really only need one of these
(setq visible-bell nil)
(setq ring-bell-function 'ignore)
```

Comment: @ShiyuMou You're welcome! Please also click on the check mark next to my answer; it will mark this as the accepted answer for others to easily see.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know, I'm new user so I didn't know that before. I have done that, thank you. :)